# is there a way to use custom range?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Im trying to implement custom date range, is there any way to use ref api to do this? Im using custom toolbar component where I have next,today,prev buttons working with calendar ref, but I also want to have 2 date inputs, one is start date, second is end date, but unfortunately I cant figure out how to use ref to change calendar view dates

```
const CustomCalendarHeader: React.FC<Props> = ({
  calendarRef,
  currentDate,
  setCurrentDate,
}) => {
  const ref = calendarRef.current!.getApi();

  const nextHandle = () => {
    ref.next();
  };
  const prevHandle = () => {
    ref.prev();
  };
  const todayHandle = () => {
    ref.today();
  };
  const dayHandle = () => {
    ref.changeView('resourceTimelineDay');
  };
  const weekHandle = () => {
    ref.changeView('resourceTimelineWeek');
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',

        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        px: 2,
        mb: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', gap: 2, flexGrow: 0.3 }}
      >
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={dayHandle}>
          Day
        </Button>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={weekHandle}>
          Week
        </Button>

        <Typography>Custom: </Typography>
        <TextField type="date" size="small" sx={{ maxWidth: '125px' }} />
        -
        <TextField type="date" size="small" sx={{ maxWidth: '125px' }} />
       
      </Box>
      <ButtonGroup
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}
      >
        <Button onClick={prevHandle}>Prev</Button>
        <Button onClick={todayHandle}>Today</Button>
        <Button onClick={nextHandle}>Next</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

and my Calendar component is looking like this:

```
<FullCalendar
                eventDrop={handleResizeOrRedropEvent}
                eventResize={handleResizeOrRedropEvent}
                droppable={true}
                eventReceive={handleEventReceive}
                viewDidMount={handleViewChange}
                ref={refCalendar as LegacyRef<FullCalendar> | undefined}
                nowIndicator
                dayMaxEvents
                timeZone="UTC"
                height="80vh"
                datesSet={(arg) => setCurrentDate(arg)}
                // visibleRange={{
                //   start: currentDate?.startStr,
                //   end: currentDate?.endStr,
                // }}
                displayEventTime={false}
                eventClick={handleEventClick}
                eventsSet={handleEvents}
                weekends={true}
                editable={true}
                selectable={true}
                // selectMirror={true}
                plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                events={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames]}
                resources={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames].map((timeframe) => ({
                  id: `${timeframe.type}-${timeframe.title}`,
                  title: timeframe.title,
                  type: timeframe.type,
                  ...('children' in timeframe && {
                    children: timeframe.children,
                  }),
                }))}
                resourceGroupField="type"
                resourceAreaWidth={'20%'}
                initialView="resourceTimeline"
                eventContent={renderEventContent}
                headerToolbar={{
                  left: '',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: '',
                }}
              />
            )}
```

searched in docs, but only vound `visibleRange` that is not actually working for me alongside with `datesSet`, it causes infinite `setState` calls

Comment: Putting a call to visibleRange inside the datesSet makes no sense. That'll set the date again, which then triggers the datesSet callback, which calls visibleRange, which then sets the date again, which...you get the picture. That's why you're getting an infinite loop.  Normally to set a calendar option after the calendar has been initialised, you call the `setOption` method - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options. In react that should be accessible via the API - see the "Calendar API" section of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Comment: @ADyson idk why but few days ago one guy posted an answer about `ref.setOption` that helped me but he deleted his message, also thank you about this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is to use `setOption` as @ADyson mentioned, it will look like this one in my custom header:

function to accept input`s changes:

```
const handleDateRangeChange = () => {
    const startDate = (
      document.getElementById('start_date') as HTMLInputElement
    ).value;
    const endDate = (document.getElementById('end_date') as HTMLInputElement)
      .value;

    if (startDate && endDate) {
      ref.setOption('visibleRange', {
        start: startDate,
        end: endDate,
      });
    }
  };
```

JSX of my custom range inputs:

```
          <Typography>Custom: </Typography>
          <TextField
            id="start_date"
            type="date"
            size="small"
            sx={{ maxWidth: '125px' }}
            onChange={handleDateRangeChange}
          />
          -
          <TextField
            id="end_date"
            type="date"
            size="small"
            sx={{ maxWidth: '125px' }}
            onChange={handleDateRangeChange}
          />
```